# Summary Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have following data

```
ID                                    Status
5bcb5961-20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c   1
140c7f17-dba5-4bc8-1fb-062d1325c399   5
5bcb5961-20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c   5
5bcb5961-20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c   0
```

I want an output in summary form.

```
ID                                     Status_1  Status_5   Status_0
5bcb5961-d20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c   1         1          1
140c7f17-dba5-4bc8-b1fb-062d1325c399   0         1          0
```

Can I get query for this output?

Comment: Please tell what about `Status_0` value for `5bcb5961-20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
      ID
    , Status_1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 END)
    , Status_5 = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 5 THEN 1 END)
    , Status_0 = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 0 THEN 1 END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: OP does not want 1 for Status_0 column in his output for ID: 5bcb5961-d20e-41b7-8af0-87ffe127830c

Comment: Yes, Either he wants 0 when status is 0 or else you will need to change your query.

Comment: Yes, it is 1. Let me change my mistake.